# Python: I'm trying to get TKinter to take a user input for a number after pressing a button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to get it so after a number is entered into the text box, the program can then read it and take it in as a variable I can use for a formula later on but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so I can get it to read the input.

Here's where I'm at so far.

```py
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import *
from itertools import cycle

window = Tk()
window.title("Title")
window.minsize(width=700, height=300)

canvas = Canvas(width=900, height=400)
canvas.create_image(50, 100)
canvas.grid(column=3,row=3)

TEXT = "MENU"

first_button_pressed = False


def second_ent():
  pass

def first_button_pressed():
  first_button.destroy()
  second_button.destroy()
  first_button_input = Entry()
  first_button_input.grid(column=2, row=1)
  label.config(text = "Enter a number.")
  first_ent_button = Button(window, text="Enter", command=first_ent)
  first_ent_button.grid(column=2, row=2)

def first_ent():
  number_entered = int(first_button_input.textinput("1.0", "end-1c"))
  print(number_entered)  

def second_button_pressed():
  phys_button.destroy()
  mag_button.destroy()
  MAG_input = Entry()
  MAG_input.grid(column=2, row=1)
  label.config(text = "Enter the Yo-Kai's Spirit stat!")
  mag_ent_button = Button(window, text="Enter", command=mag_ent)
  mag_ent_button.grid(column=2, row=2)


label = Label(text=TEXT)
label.grid(column=2, row=0)
first_button = Button(window, text="first button", command=first_button_pressed)
first_button.grid(column=2, row=1)
second_button = Button(window, text="second button", command=second_button_pressed)
second_button.grid(column=2, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

I've looked around towards other solutions saying to use .get() but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your `Entry()` variables are local variables, so if you are using it outside the functions, then make sure to globalise the variable first using `global first_button_input` inside the function

Comment: I took your advice and tried that but I seem to get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

That is bad practice for input in line 33.

Change this:

```
number_entered = int(first_button_input.textinput("1.0", "end-1c"))
```

to:

```
number_entered = int(first_button_input.get())
```

Also comment out line 26 `#first_button_input = Entry(window)` and put this to line 45. So you don't need to declare global.

Output after clicking first button:

[image]

You will see print in debug.